# Why can't I access map key with an int?

Tags: go

I create a map like so:

```
board := make(map[int]map[string]string)
```

I add some numbers to it so data is formatted like follows.

```
1 : map("a", "b" ..)
```

I then pass in a position. "a1" and this is where I hit a wall.

```
func (checkers *Checkers) setPiece(piece string, coordinates string) {
    lett := string(coordinates[0]);
    num, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(coordinates[1]), 0, 64)

    if err != nil {
        panic("Invalid coordinate format")
    }


    row := checkers.board[num]
}
```

I get the follow error: 'cannot use num (type int64) as type int in map index'

Why do I get this error? How do I access a key in the map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to convert from int64 to int. like so:

```
checkers.board[int(num)]
```

However, if all you want is to parse an int out of a string, you should use `strconv.AtoI` for that. It will return (int, error) so you don't have to convert it. Also, keep in mind that the way your code is currently written will not work for 2-digit numbers or 2-letter prefixes. This may be by design.

Comment: I am trying to make checkers as my first go project. The board is 1-8 and a-h which is why I took this approach. I don't know if it is correct, was going to ask for feedback when finished :)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
num, err := strconv.Atoi(string(coordinates[1]))
```

which returns an `int`.

> [Package strconv](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/)
>
> [func Atoi](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi)
>
> ```
> func Atoi(s string) (i int, err error)
> ```
>
> `Atoi` is shorthand for `ParseInt(s, 10, 0)`.